# Проверить, является ли файл jpeg картинкой

Tags: php

Как проверить на PHP, является ли изменяемый файл jpeg картинкой?
Иногда файл имеет расширение jpeg, при изменении размера выдается ошибка:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x3c 0x21
```

Скачал картинку на Windows и она даже не просматривается.

Сейчас мой код выглядит следующим образом:

```
$file = /var/images/photo.jpg;   
$image = new Imagick($file);
$image->cropThumbnailImage(549, 366);
$image->setImageFormat( 'jpeg' );
$url_name_gal = ''.$path_img.''.$r['id'].'idxmain5.jpg';
$image->writeImage($url_name_gal);
```

Как перед изменением размера проверить, является ли файл правильным jpeg?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(exif_imagetype($filepath) != IMAGETYPE_JPEG){
    echo 'Not a JPEG image';
}
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141227/check-if-the-image-is-a-jpeg)